# How thorough should I be when reviewing chapters for a book?

Tags: editors, books

I'm editing my first book and, as part of the process, I have to review the chapters from the different authors. I'm doubting about how deep the review should be, I mean for example If I think that if the authors include a certain figure the section will be more clear, should I comment it? Or do you think that it is personal style and each author should keep his/hers?

Comment: Try your best to make the book a high quality.